# Is PKCS7 signing possible on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, passbook, pkcs#7

I need to create a PKCS7 signature for some data using my Python app running on Google App Engine (GAE).  More specifically, I am trying to create a PKCS7 signature of an Apple Passbook pass manifest; the Passbook pass requires the PKCS7 signature file to be present in order to be a complete and valid pass.

I have spent almost a week researching and trying to no avail.

I can successfully create the signature using openssl command line on my local PC with:

```
openssl smime -binary -sign -certfile WWDR.pem -signer certificate.pem -inkey key.pem -in manifest.json -out signature -outform DER
```

I can also successfully create the signature using M2Crypto library on my local PC with:

```
from M2Crypto import BIO, SMIME, X509

s = SMIME.SMIME()
s.load_key('identity.pem')         # my certificate and private key

x509 = X509.load_cert('WWDR.pem')  # Apple's intermediate certificate
sk = X509.X509_Stack()
sk.push(x509)
s.set_x509_stack(sk)

p7 = s.sign(bio_manifest, SMIME.PKCS7_DETACHED | SMIME.PKCS7_BINARY)
pkcs7_buffer = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
p7.write_der(pkcs7_buffer)

f = open('signature', 'w')
f.write(pkcs7_buffer.read())
f.close()
```

However, M2Crypto is a wrapper to OpenSSL which is not supported on GAE.

GAE supports the pycrypto library, but it doesn't seem this library has support for PKCS7 signing.

I've also looked at tlslite, which is a pure python implementation and therefore should be supported on GAE, but it also doesn't seem to have support for PKCS7 signing.

I'm looking for guidance from anyone that has been able to successfully create a PKCS7 signature on GAE.  If you could point me to a pure python library or any other solution, I'd really appreciate it.

Otherwise, I feel like I've reached the boundary of what is possible with GAE and will be looking to move my app to another platform.  I'm a bit flabbergasted that it has been this difficult and that GAE doesn't support the openssl library given the importance of data security; it appears they aren't serious about providing a web app service that offers support for anything beyond the basics.  Unless (hopefully) I've missed the obvious.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Already look in direction of keyczar ? http://www.keyczar.org

Comment: @olituks I did review the keyczar documentation.  It doesn't generate pkcs7 signatures either.  :(

Comment: To bad. In certain condition you can use the padding PKCS5 in place of PKCS7 maybe it's ok for you. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding